# VBA: action based on multiple ranges

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, vba

I am very new to VBA and I tried googling several times before posting here. I apologize if something like this has already been asked and answered.

I have a list of numbers from A3:A22 in Column A on Sheet 1 and I am trying to assign a grade based on the value of each number in Column A Sheet 1 in A7:A26 on Sheet 2.

The sample logic I am trying to use is

```
If value < 10 Then Grade = 'A'
Else If 10 <= value < 20 then Grade = 'B'
Else If 20 <= value < 50 then Grade = 'C'
Else If 50 <= value < 70 then Grade = 'D'
Else Grade = 'E'
```

How can I achieve this? I dont want to use excel formula because I have several such logics and excel nested if function can get cumbersome.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this question is a bit like "how can I write this VBA code in VBA?" :]

Answer (score 0):

I would, instead of using VBA, just use a formula in the cell. Something like this in cell A7 (to be copied down):

```
=if(Sheet1!A3>70,"E",if(Sheet1!A3>50,"D",if(Sheet1!A3>20,"C",if(Sheet1!A3>10,"B","A"))))
```

If you MUST make it in VBA, this should work:

```
Dim SourceStart As Long, DestinationStart As Long, SourceEnd As Long
Dim Grade As String, CurrentRow As Long
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet, DestinationSheet As Worksheet

SourceStart = 3
SourceEnd = 22
DestinationStart = 7
Set SourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set DestinationSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

For CurrentRow = SourceStart To SourceEnd
    Select Case SourceSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value
        Case Is > 70
            Grade = "E"
        Case Is > 50
            Grade = "D"
        Case Is > 20
            Grade = "C"
        Case Is > 10
            Grade = "B"
        Case Else
            Grade = "A"
    End Select
    DestinationSheet.Cells(CurrentRow + DestinationStart - SourceStart, 1).Value = Grade
Next
```

This is NOT a good example for how to code for reusability. For example, the grades should be made into some sort of data format, so you can use different grading scales in different places. The sources and destinations shouldn't be hardcoded. The worksheets shouldn't be hardcoded. But without knowing a use case it cannot be properly coded to take these variables into account.

Comment: Thanks Michael. sorry, I forgot to mention in my comments that what I have posted in a sample. I have several such condition which would make using excel formula nonviable.

Comment: It must be a pretty big worksheet if it's going to get cumbersome. Do the numbers change depending on other data? That can all be incorporated into a formula, too. Using VBA would mean (usually) the user must initiate some action for the calculations to take place, so the formula is better.

Comment: Yes, what I have posted is just a start. But there will be more to build on it. The user would have to click a button to initiate the run of the logic.

Comment: Then some information seems to be missing. It looks like you just have the single range, A7:A26, that should hold the grades, and A3:A22 that holds the source data. You could write VBA to iterate over these ranges, but I don't yet see why it should be VBA instead of a formula. Can you provide any additional variables, such as other ranges that would need computing?

Answer (score 0):

Where nested IFs are making a formula rather complex and the likes of VBA not required for volumes/frequency a standard solution is to apply a lookup table. Say the following is a named range `cTable`:

```
0   A
10  B
20  C
50  D
69  E
```

Then for a lookup value in A7 the following formula may serve:

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,gTable,2)
```

and may be copied down to suit (ie in this case to `A26`).

By excluding the fourth (optional) parameter and sorting `gTable` ascending, [VLOOKUP](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function) will search for the next lower value where it does not find an exact match. For example, if looking up a Grade for `9`, rather than 'giving up' because `9` is not in `gTable`, it will drop down to the next level (`0`) and return the match (`A`) for that.

Since the table is a Named Range it need not be on the same sheet (so for example might be hidden).

The VLOOKUP formula is a quarter of the length of the formula offered in @Michael Foster's answer and `gTable` may be easier to update, if required, than nested IF formulae or VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Excel formula for that would be:

```
=Lookup(A3,{0,10,20,50,70;"A","B","C","D","E"})
```

or

```
=MID("ABCCCDDEEEE",A3/10+1,1)
```

which in VBA will be

```
['Sheet 2'!A7:A26] = [MID("ABCCCDDEEEE",'Sheet 1'!A3:A22/10+1,1)]
```